# Rename Column name in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to change column name to a new name.

eg: Column name is "Sr.No."
I want to change it to "ID"

i used

```
sp_RENAME 'Matrix.Sr.No.','ID','COLUMN';
```

but it gives me error.

```
Msg 15253, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 105
Syntax error parsing SQL identifier 'Matrix.Sr.No.'.
```

Comment: Very smart to rename that column - it was a terrible name.

Comment: You should note that renaming column name will break your queries, stored procedures etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Matrix.Sr.No` means the `No` column in the `Sr` table of the `Matrix` schema in the current database.  Try escaping the name:

```
sp_RENAME 'Matrix.[Sr.No.]','ID','COLUMN';
```

Comment: i have tried your query but it gives me the error "Either the parameter objname is ambiguous or the claimed objtype (COLUMN) is wrong."

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
EXEC sp_rename 
    @objname = 'table_name.old_column_name', 
    @newname = 'new_column_name', 
    @objtype = 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: `EXEC` makes this work within a stored procedure or query with several queries.